# Why does event.preventDefault() does not always work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I'm submitting through ajax. I have to check the input field values before submitting it, but no matter what I do, the form keeps submitting even though it is not passing the test. Does anyone know why this is going on? If you see my code below, the form submission function checks the values and returns false if the criteria is not met. However, for some reason return false nor event.preventDefault() are working. I have no idea what's going on. Maybe I'm overlooking something?...

```
function checkPass(){

    var newPass = $("#newPass").val();
    var confirmPass = $("#confirmPass").val();

    if(newPass != confirmPass || confirmPass == '') { 
        $( "#confirmDiv" ).addClass( "has-warning" );
        $( "#confirmError" ).addClass( "animated fadeInDown" );
        $( "#confirmError" ).addClass( "text-warning" );
        document.getElementById("confirmError").style.fontSize = '14px';
        document.getElementById("confirmError").innerHTML = "The passwords don't match.<br>";
        event.preventDefault();
        return false; 
    } else {
        $( "#confirmDiv" ).removeClass( "has-warning" );
        document.getElementById("confirmError").innerHTML = "";
        $( "#confirmError" ).removeClass( "animated fadeInDown" );
        return true; 
    }

}

function updatePassword(){

  checkPass();

  event.preventDefault();

  var url = "updatePassword.php";
  var form = $("#updatePassword");

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(a) {
      if (a == "Success!") {

         alert(a);

         document.getElementById('updatePassword').reset();

      } else {

         alert(a);

      }

    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Try passing the `event` explicitly rather than depending on it being globally defined.

Comment: ``function updatePassword(){`` should be function ``updatePassword(event){``

Comment: same goes for `checkPass()` -> checkPass(event)`

Comment: how is these methods called? is the error browser specific?

Comment: Adding event to my functions didn't work :/

Comment: @ArunPJohny the problem is not browser specific

Comment: From where you are triggering `checkPass()` function. I mean a click, select or something like that, there you have to set this `event` then only you can prevent its following action as you expected.

Comment: ``event.preventDefault()`` doesn't work this way, it won't stop code execution. You already have ``checkPass()`` if it returns true execute following ``$.ajax`` else don't call it.

Comment: @Sinto the function is being called when the submit button is clicked. I added the vent there as well, but didn't work

Comment: can you add the code line of button

Comment: @Carlos is there any error in your browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event parameter to use event.preventDefault(), by the way, you're using `return false` and that should be okay to prevent. But looking at your code carefully, I found one issue. You're calling checkPass inside updatePassword and the rest of the code

```
function updatePassword(){

  checkPass();
  // rest of the code still runs if checkPass returns false
```

So, what you need to do here is to use a condition:

```
function updatePassword(){

  if(checkPass()) {
   // rest of the code
```

Now, you're correctly preventing the behavior. Alternatively, you may fix the code by supplying event parameter in updatePassword if you want to use preventDefault().

---

The test case for you to analyse:

```js
function test() {
  return false
}
function test2(){
  if(test())
  console.log('test2')
}
function test3(){
  test()
  console.log('test3')
}
test2()
test3()
```

Comment: "*You need to pass the event parameter to use event.preventDefault(),*" Unfortunately... no. In browsers that do support the non-standard window.event global, you can very well prevent the current event's default behavior by using `window.event.preventDefault()`. And return false in DOM2 event handlers does nothing at all. You probably got confused with jQuery event handlers.

Comment: @Kaiido I am thinking of the method bind in an element... hmm, I might have confused.

Comment: There is no such method. (jQuery objects do have it though)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am assuming that in your form at the time of onsubmit event  you are calling "updatePassword()" method I think you should make some change like this and it's working for me I hop it will work for you

```
function updatePassword() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (checkPass()) {

            var url = "updatePassword.php";
            var form = $("#updatePassword");

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (a) {
                    if (a == "Success!") {

                        alert(a);

                        document.getElementById('updatePassword').reset();

                    } else {

                        alert(a);

                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }
```